# Rayleigh-Ritz under LOBPCG : Nested iteration?

Tags: algorithms, eigenvalues

I am trying to understand the basic LOBPCG algorithm, as used in popular python libraries,
primarily from [the suggested resource on wiki](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07458).

LOBPCG involves a subroutine to compute the coefficients of the orthonormal basis.
This computation is equivalent to another eigenvalue problem; it is equivalent to finding the optimal step size.
The Rayleigh-Ritz solves this eigenvalue problem, by projecting the given matrix on a smaller subspace.

I am not able to identify how exactly this *projected eigenvalue problem* is solved ??
Specifically, [Algo2, step 4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07458); "who is finally solving" ?

As suggested [here, pg5.](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Ebai/ECS231/Handouts/eig.pdf), Rayleigh-Ritz utilize *standard methods*.

1. What are these standard methods ? QR,Power-iteration ?
2. Which of them are popularly implemented in python modules, such as scipy, torch etc. ?
3. Considering this method as an iterative algorithm, does it mean that LOBPCG have nested iteration ?